# how to join a different homegroup?

Tags: windows-8

all my computers are on homegroup "Mark" and the HTPC computer is on a different homegroup... how do I get it to leave that homegroup and join "Mark"?

I tried to leave the homegroup, then it said I was invited to join a homegroup and when I accepted the invitation it just rejoined the homegroup that already existed before on the HTPC.., not the "Mark" one that all the other computers use

Comment: leave the group again and the search for available homegroups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out...

the offending PC (the HTPC) was the only one on my network using a windows live account.. so I converted that to a local account, and voila... now all 3 windows 8 computers are on the same homegroup! (after entering the homegroup password)

Comment: That may be the case. However I will point out. I use Windows 8.1 I use Windows Live account on this OS for login as it is the default setup when installing. Allows Skydrive cloud storage integration and such. All the others comps in my network are on Windows 7 so no Windows Live integration. All my comps are logged in to Homegroup and accessible. It may be that you need to do Homegroup setup on the Windows 8 machine. I had the same issue as you and when I had all my comps leave the group I re-setup Homgroup via my Win 8 comp. So it is probably that you need to set it up via Win 8.

Comment: I really don't think Microsoft would not have included the functionality of Live ID if was going to mess up their Homgroup feature.

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible to have one Homegroup per network. How ever there is a bug that allows a second Homegroup in Windows 7. Easiest fix is to have all your computers on the network leave the Homegroup. I would power cycle the router and modem as well by unplugging them for 30 seconds. Then plug the modem back in, first let power up then plug in your router. Then go to any computer that is on the network and set up Homegroups. Get password and go to each computer and rejoin the Homegroup. That should fix it. Let us know if it does.